# Converting Line Chart to Google Annotation Chart in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-visualization, web-frontend

Currently I have an angular line chart and grid showing the monthly performance for a stock portfolio.

[image: Current Charts]

The grid is fine right now, but I would like to tweak the chart so that it looks more like the google finance chart, giving a cumulative return that can be zoomed in and out for the time period like google finance allows (preferably 1 year, 2 year, all, and custom).
It looks like Google's Annotation Chart is the closest to this.

Can anyone give some tips on how to switch the style of graphs I'm currently using? How can I make the chart show (1+monthly returns in the grid) cumulatively multiplied together? Thank you

Controller:

```
angular.module('ReturnsCtrl', []).controller('ReturnsController', function($scope, $http, $filter, FUNDS, DATES, FUNDMAP, BENCHMARKS, BENCHMARKMAP) {

    $scope.start = new Date(DATES.minDate);
    $scope.end = new Date(DATES.maxDate)
    $scope.minDate = new Date(DATES.minDate);
    $scope.maxDate = new Date(DATES.maxDate);

    $scope.items = FUNDS;
    $scope.benchmarks = BENCHMARKS

    var cellColor = function(grid, row, col, rowIndex, colIndex) {
      var val = grid.getCellValue(row, col);
      if(val < 0) {
        return 'red';
      }
    }

    $scope.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: [{ field: 'year', displayName: 'Year' },
                  { field: 'January', displayName: 'Jan',
                    cellClass: cellColor },
                  { field: 'February', displayName: 'Feb',
                    cellClass: cellColor},
                  { field: 'March', displayName: 'Mar' ,
                    cellClass: cellColor},
                  { field: 'April', displayName: 'Apr' ,
                    cellClass: cellColor},
                  { field: 'May', displayName: 'May',
                    cellClass: cellColor },
                  { field: 'June', displayName: 'June',
                    cellClass: cellColor },
                  { field: 'July', displayName: 'July',
                    cellClass: cellColor },
                  { field: 'August', displayName: 'Aug',
                    cellClass: cellColor },
                  { field: 'September', displayName: 'Sept',
                    cellClass: cellColor },
                  { field: 'October', displayName: 'Oct',
                    cellClass: cellColor },
                  { field: 'November', displayName: 'Nov',
                    cellClass: cellColor },
                  { field: 'December', displayName: 'Dec',
                    cellClass: cellColor },
                  { field: 'YearlyReturn', diplayNmae: 'Yearly', cellClass: cellColor}]
  }

  $scope.calculate = function() {
    var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var shortMonth = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    $scope.chartData = {
      returns: [],
      labels: [],
      series: []
    }
    var fundName = FUNDMAP[$scope.data.fund]
    $scope.config = {
      params:{
        startDate:$filter('date')($scope.start, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
        endDate:$filter('date')($scope.end, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
        cik:$scope.data.fund,
        startingAmount:10000,
        benchmark:$scope.data.benchmark
      }
    }

    $http.get('/api/returns', $scope.config).success(function(data) {

      var labels = []
      var returnsList = [];
      var values = []
      $scope.chartData.series.push(fundName)
      for(var d in data['requested']) {
        for(var i in months)
          if(data['requested'][d].hasOwnProperty(months[i])) {
            labels.push(data['requested'][d]['year'] + " " + shortMonth[i] )
            values.push(data['requested'][d][months[i]])
          }
      }
      $scope.chartData.returns.push(values)

      angular.forEach(data['benchmark'], function(value, key) {
        values = []
        for(var d in value) {
          for(var i in months) {
            if(value[d].hasOwnProperty(months[i])) {
              values.push(value[d][months[i]])
            }
          }
        }
        $scope.chartData.series.push(BENCHMARKMAP[$scope.data.benchmark])
        $scope.chartData.returns.push(values)
      })

      $scope.gridOptions.data = data['requested']

      $scope.chartData.labels = labels

    }).error(function() {
      alert("Error");
    })
  };


  $scope.noWeekendsPredicate = function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      return day > 0 && day < 6;
    }

    $scope.greaterThanStart = function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      if(day === 0 || day === 6) {
          return false;
      }

      if(date.getYear()!=$scope.start.getYear()) return date.getYear() > $scope.start.getYear();
      else if(date.getMonth()!=$scope.start.getMonth()) return date.getMonth()> $scope.start.getMonth();
      else if(date.getDate()!=$scope.start.getDate()) return date.getDate() > $scope.start.getDate();
      return false;
    }

});
```

View:

```
<html>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1> Returns </h1>


    <form class="form-inline">
      <label for="singleSelectFund">Hedge Fund:</label>
      <select name="singleSelectFund" id="singleSelectFund" ng-model="data.fund" required>
        <option value="">---Please select---</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in items" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
      </select>

      <label for="singleSelectBenchmark">Benchmark:</label>
      <select name="singleSelectBenchmark" id="singleSelectBenchmark" ng-model="data.benchmark" required>
        <option value="">---Please select---</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in benchmarks" value="{{option.code}}">{{option.name}}</option>
      </select><br>

         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    </form>

    <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="chartData.returns"
      chart-labels="chartData.labels" chart-legend="true"
      chart-click="onClick" chart-series="chartData.series">
    </canvas>

    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>


  </div>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not really sure where to start, or if I can even use the same controller/ do I need to create another javascript file to use the google annotation chart.